# Why is my Parse Cloud Code request 'unauthorized?'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform

I'm trying to run Parse cloud code for the first time from an AngularJS app. I keep getting the Parse.Error 'unauthorized' in my console.log. I've initialized Parse in my application and JS keys. Where am I going wrong?

Angular Code Format:

```
$scope.runSomething = function () {
    Parse.Cloud.run('nameFunction', req.body, {
         success: function (result){
        },
         error: function (error){
           console.log(error);
        }
 })
```

I derive the req.body for the Parse.Cloud.run from prestanding info in the $scope.runSomething function.

My truncated main.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('nameFunction', function(request, response){
     Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
     //Do Stuff})
```

I'm sure I'm missing something small but I have no idea what.

Comment: Best guesses (in order of likelihood): a) bad form of req.body... test with hardcoding an object there, b) wrong keys ... rule out by getting any other server call -- like a query -- to work, c) double check that the function name matches.  Another thing to try is CURL, just to see if you can get it to run.  The docs are very helpful with this.  (see https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions-calling).  It will insert your keys in the example call if you select your app.  Pay close attention to the format of the body after `-d`

Comment: the req.body is an array of Parse Ids. Is this an issue?

Comment: Early indication looks like it may have something to do with the req.body being an array instead of an object . . .

Comment: Ok, now I'm getting: { code: 141, message: 'success/error was not called' }. My function is saving data to the database. How do the before/after save options relate to run for doing this sort of thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're close.  Cloud functions (including before/after functions) must call success or error on the response object to properly complete, so...

```
Parse.Cloud.define('nameFunction', function(request, response){
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var someParam = request.params.someParam;
    doSomePromiseReturningThing(someParam).then(function(result) {
        response.success(result);
    }, function (error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks danh, but I keep getting the error no matter where I put my success/error call. I'm going to set up a new question to deal with this since my code is somewhat elaborate for this.  I will try to simplify it.